# How to make selenium click this buttion?

Tags: python, selenium, findelement

[click to see button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDePK.jpg)

I want to make selenium click the above button so i used:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
generate=driver.find_element_by_link_text("GENERATE EXCEL FILE TO DOWNLOAD")
generate.click()
```

But selenium wasnt able to find it, so how do i make selenium find that button and click it?

PS: I'm using Python

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a little bit 'wait' before performing clicking to this element, something like:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.wait_for_element_to_appear
generate=driver.find_element_by_link_text("GENERATE EXCEL FILE TO DOWNLOAD")
generate.click()
```

Please search for it because it's quite simple

Comment: The thing is the website has many buttons like this, so if i put wait everytime a button like that appears, it would defeat the entire purpose of automating the task

Comment: @DivyamSureka If a lot buttons having the same text as you said, so you must differentiate them using xpath

Comment: Yeah, but when i inspect the button, i get the following:<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-bind="trans.HEAD_LOGIN">Login</button>, so how should i proceed?

Comment: @DivyamSureka Please try following xpaths:
(//button[text()='Login'])[1] ; 
(//button[text()='Login'])[2] ; 
(//button[text()='Login'])[3] ;

Answer (score 0):

You should use xpath. This is the best way to do it but you have to find x_path for your element.
For example like this:

```
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='lang' and @value='Python']")[0]
python_button.click()
```

Maybe this link could help you:
https://pythonspot.com/selenium-click-button/

Moreover you could try do select it by the id:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
```

And also by the visible text could work:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Python Tutorial")
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried this but the html code is too complicated and hence i cant find the name and  value. Hence is there any way?

Comment: Can you share the Website ? Because you should be able to select the element and then get the xpath in most browsers.

Comment: https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login, this is the link, i want to login and download monthly files from many different accounts, which is a very monotonus task, and hence i was hoping to ease my task using selenium. So is it possible to click the button?

Comment: Of course it is possible, just right klick on your download button then inspect this elemtn and you can see the full xpath

Comment: When i inspected the button this came :<button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary" data-ng-bind="trans.HEAD_LOGIN">Login</button>, so how should i proceed?

Comment: in most browser you can select the the item and then copy it in xpath